# How to use the move command on Windows, to move all files inside a folder when using quotation symbol?

Tags: windows, command-line, filesystems

I currently have these two folders:

- oldFolder

  - news

    - info.json
- newFolder

  - news

    - info.json

I want to use the move command, to move all files in the oldFolder to the new Folder. I have tried this: `move "G:\Program Files (x86)\oldFolder\" "G:\Program Files (x86)\newFolder\"`, but this actually move the entire oldFolder inside newFolder.

So, I have tried this: `move "G:\Program Files (x86)\oldFolder\*.*" "G:\Program Files (x86)\newFolder\"`, but this gave me this error: `The syntax of the file, directory, or volume name is incorrect.`

An idea?

Regards

Comment: It's not clear if `info.json` is meant to be a file or a folder. IMO the syntax of the [move](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html) command doesn't include an option for files ***and*** trees/subtrees. Try: `robocopy "G:\Program Files (x86)\oldFolder" "G:\Program Files (x86)\newFolder" * /E /MOVE`

Comment: @LotPings Working! Just post your comment as an answer, and I will put it right! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if info.json is meant to be a file or a folder.

IMO the syntax of the move command doesn't include an option for files ***and*** trees/subtrees.

Try:

```
robocopy "G:\Program Files (x86)\oldFolder" "G:\Program Files (x86)\newFolder" * /E /MOVE
```

This will also completely remove `oldFolder`

See syntax with `robocopy /?` or view [online](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)